# force method implementation

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Is there any way I can force a class extending a concrete class to implement one of the super class' methods in Java? What I want is something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    /* modifiers */ aMethod(){
         /* an implementation */
    }
}

class SubClass extends SomeClass {
   /* if I don't reimplement aMethod() here, I get a compiler error */
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like an abstract method?  Then SomeClass needs to be abstract though.

Comment: Just like an abstract method, but I want to be able to instantiate SomeClass, so it cannot be abstract.

Comment: Hmm, you could make SomeClass private and provide a factory, then make a second public class that extends SomeClass with an abstract method.  This is kind of weird though.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is part of a test question, which I did today, but I've been thinking about it for some time now and couldn't find an answer, so I figured I'd just post it here. I am starting to think there is no answer, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is supposed to be "no," unless you've got some sort of crazy byte code rewriting framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this two ways - with an `interface` or an `abstract class`

Below is an example of both.

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class SomeClass {

    public abstract void aMethod();

}


public class SubClass extends SomeClass {

    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        // An error would occur if aMethod isn't here.
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface SomeClass { // You'd probably want to name it something different

    public abstract void aMethod();

}


public class SubClass extends SomeClass {

    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        // An error would occur if aMethod isn't here.
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Furthermore, you can only have abstract methods in an interface - whereas in an abstract class, the methods can have a body. An abstract class is commonly used in APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the class the called the method, if the calling class is the same as parent class then throw an exception like that

```
public class SomeClass {

    public void method() throws NoSuchMethodException, Exception {
        System.out.println("override me");
        if(SomeClass.class.getMethod("method", null).getDeclaringClass().equals(SomeClass.class)) {
            throw new Exception("Not Overriden");
        }
    }

}

public class SubClass extends SomeClass {

    public SubClass() {

    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("hiii");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you cane make super class as Interface so that the subclass have to provide the implementation for the super class method because the method present in Interface by default abstract.

```
public interface SomeClass {

public abstract void aMethod();

}

public class SubClass implements SomeClass {
   public void aMethod() {
    // provide implementation or it will give error
}

}
```

Comment: This doesn't add new information for this question, which hasn't already been addressed in the other answer.